# Do you need to be at the airport as a writer of declaration of guarantee for a Schengen visa?

Tags: visas, schengen, regulations

For a family member to apply for a Schengen visa, I provided an official declaration of guarantee. Now I appear to be traveling myself when my family member enters Schengen, so I won't be able to fetch her from the airport. On [Wikitravel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Travel_in_the_Schengen_Zone) I read:

> Even if you possess a valid visa, actual entry may still be denied/refused if you are unable to satisfy the border officer's questions and/or requests to see documents.

Can a border officer require personal confirmation from an official declaration of guarantee and what happens if the declarer is not at the airport?

Comment: Is it a guarantee you will house them for a regular Schengen visa or did they get a free spouse visa to travel with you? And will you be in the country with them, only not at the airport or are they traveling alone for the whole trip?

Comment: It is a family visit and I will indeed provide the housing for a regular Schengen visa. I will be out of the country in the first week though and the visa holder will be staying with other family members.

Comment: There is no requirement for you to be *at the airport*. You wouldn't be at the passport check anyway but only at the exit of the baggage claim area so if anything being reachable by phone would seem more useful. The part about not actually housing your visitor is a little more tricky, it could be conceived as having lied on the visa application but if your visitor explains that he or she will visit several family members, can explain how he or she will get to your place, etc., it should be fine.

Comment: @Relaxed you could probably put that as an answer...

Answer (score 3):

I have issued the same declaration multiple times before, and I was never required to be at the airport or anything like that. There's no official requirement for that.

Just in case, even though it's completely not necessary, you may want to be available by phone. However usually border controls aren't strict at that point, the only thing they usually ask is health insurance. I don't know anyone who ever had troubles with that.

Bon Voyage!